# RingCentral: Build Failed Task failed with exit code 65: Carthage installation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode10, ringcentral

I have a project that was build in Xcode9.
Now I am updating it to Xcode10.
I am using RingCentral iOS SDK.

But whenever I update the SDK, it shows this error:
I have tried almost all methods for cleaning and building derived data

Carthage version = 0.32.0

Xcode version = 10.1

Please help, I am stuck and cannot run the project

```
carthage update --platform iOS
*** Fetching ringcentral-swift
*** Fetching CryptoSwift
*** Fetching objective-c
*** Fetching Alamofire
*** Fetching ObjectMapper
*** Checking out ObjectMapper at "3.4.2"
*** Checking out Alamofire at "4.8.1"
*** Checking out ringcentral-swift at "1.0.1"
*** Checking out CryptoSwift at "0.14.0"
*** Checking out objective-c at "v4.8.5"
*** xcodebuild output can be found in /var/folders/49/ckkpnf9n6lgbfsfp407twf840000gn/T/carthage-xcodebuild.gTqjHT.log
*** Building scheme "Alamofire iOS" in Alamofire.xcworkspace
*** Building scheme "CryptoSwift" in CryptoSwift.xcworkspace
*** Building scheme "Framework (iOS)" in PubNub.xcworkspace
*** Building scheme "ObjectMapper-iOS" in ObjectMapper.xcworkspace
*** Building scheme "RingCentral_iOS" in RingCentral.xcodeproj
Build Failed
Task failed with exit code 65:
/usr/bin/xcrun xcodebuild -project /Users/xxxxxxxxx/Downloads/MyFax\ /Carthage/Checkouts/ringcentral-swift/RingCentral.xcodeproj -scheme RingCentral_iOS -configuration Release -derivedDataPath /Users/xxxxxxxxx/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/DerivedData/10.1_10B61/ringcentral-swift/1.0.1 -sdk iphoneos ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY= CARTHAGE=YES archive -archivePath /var/folders/49/ckkpnf9n6lgbfsfp407twf840000gn/T/ringcentral-swift SKIP_INSTALL=YES GCC_INSTRUMENT_PROGRAM_FLOW_ARCS=NO CLANG_ENABLE_CODE_COVERAGE=NO STRIP_INSTALLED_PRODUCT=NO (launched in /Users/xxxxxxxxx/Downloads/MyFax /Carthage/Checkouts/ringcentral-swift)

This usually indicates that project itself failed to compile. Please check the xcodebuild log for more details: /var/folders/49/ckkpnf9n6lgbfsfp407twf840000gn/T/carthage-xcodebuild.gTqjHT.log
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If anyone is facing issue with Cartage update.

You can follow the simple steps

1- Download their repository and open their Xcode project in latest xcode.

2- Build the project using Generic iOS Device on Xcode.

3- If there are any errors in the linked frameworks -> Repeat Step 1 for the error framework

4- If build succeed, in Products folder, you will see the framework file

5- CTRL+Click (Right click) and select show in finder

6- Copy the framework file

7- Goto your project directory which is using Carthage

8- Open /YourProjectDirectory/Carthage/Build/iOS folder

9- Paste the framework file that you have generated in step-4

10- Now build your project and it should work

Happy Coding :)

Comment: i had error for object mapper in ring central, i downloaded the git for object mapper and rebuild the object mapper and then replaced it. It worked, thanks

Comment: @FastCoderz When we install the carthage on different system then we have to follow the same process? If yes, then this is not the correct solution and answer for this question. :(