# RingCentral Swift compile fail

Tags: swift, ringcentral

I am new to RingCentral. I am trying with RingCentral Swift for iOS application. I am checking the reference [here](https://github.com/ringcentral/ringcentral-swift).

I am getting following issue of compile failure:

```
*** Fetching Alamofire
*** Fetching ObjectMapper
*** Checking out ObjectMapper at "3.4.2"
*** Checking out Alamofire at "4.8.1"
*** Checking out ringcentral-swift at "1.0.1"
*** Checking out CryptoSwift at "0.14.0"
*** Checking out objective-c at "v4.8.5"
*** xcodebuild output can be found in /var/folders/49/ckkpnf9n6lgbfsfp407twf840000gn/T/carthage-xcodebuild.gTqjHT.log
*** Building scheme "Alamofire iOS" in Alamofire.xcworkspace
*** Building scheme "CryptoSwift" in CryptoSwift.xcworkspace
*** Building scheme "Framework (iOS)" in PubNub.xcworkspace
*** Building scheme "ObjectMapper-iOS" in ObjectMapper.xcworkspace
*** Building scheme "RingCentral_iOS" in RingCentral.xcodeproj
Build Failed
Task failed with exit code 65:  /usr/bin/xcrun xcodebuild -project /Users/......./Downloads
```

I searched the reason in the community but failed to understand why is the compile issue.

Please help.

Comment: If you have a near term issue, please create RingCentral support ticket so this request can be associated with your account.

Answer (score 1):

I am the author of that SDK. It has low priority because it doesn't have lots of users as the other SDKs (such as C# and JS). I've got your feedback and I will try to update the SDK this quarter. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Swift SDK hasn't been updated for years as referenced [here](https://community.ringcentral.com/questions/1541/swift-sdk-no-longer-updated.html):
The same issue was registered here: https://github.com/ringcentral/ringcentral-swift/issues/17
Maybe the Carthage version causing the issue. You can download their repository and open their Xcode project in the latest `xcode`, build the project and follow the steps here to resolve the issue: [RingCentral: Build Failed Task failed with exit code 65: Carthage installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55300973/ringcentral-build-failed-task-failed-with-exit-code-65-carthage-installation/55469994#55469994)

As a workaround, if you are building a GUI app, you can use WebView and JavaScript SDK as suggested here for the same issue: https://community.ringcentral.com/questions/89996/couldnt-build-ringcentral-library.html